How to solve this HSTS error that is propagated based on the CN and not the domain people should be going to?
We have setup a SSL cert like this:
SAN - blah.subdomain.com, blah.extranet.subdomain.com
CN - blah.subdomain.com

I am trying to setup an HSTS header in IIS 10. I have created the website specifying the host as blah.subdomain.com for bindings 80 and 443, then configured the HSTS header. When I navigate to the site blah.subdomain.com, I see the HSTS header as I expect to and the server is listed as Microsoft-IIS/10.0. There are no certificate errors; it says the site is secure. Unfortunately though, the security scanners are picking up an error with the HSTS header and it's because the scanner is navigating to blah.extranet.subdomain.com and getting served by Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, producing this error:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii 
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 
Date: Sat, 04 May 2024 04:34:39 GMT 
Connection: close 
Content-Length: 315 
The remote HTTPS server does not send the HTTP "Strict-Transport-Security" header

The error isn't technically wrong, but users shouldn't be navigating to the site using that URL. Do I need to disable Microsoft HTTPAPI 2.0 somehow? Add additional site bindings with blah.extranet.subdomain.com as the host, even though users shouldn't use an address like that?

Do you care what the security scanner says? If you must make it happy then you have two choices: remove blah.extranet.subdomain.com from the certificate or send a proper HSTS header under HTTPS from blah.extranet.subdomain.com.

I personally don't but I'm sure cybersecurity folks do. If I set the HSTS header at the server level instead of the website level in IIS, will that work? Or do I need to explicitly configure the site with more bindings with the blah.extranet.subdomain.com host?

Why don't you have IIS also serve blah.extranet.subdomain.com?
